# Flutter: Handle permission for PDF file access in Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-permissions

Since the Android 13 permission update, managing access to user storage has changed and I'm tackling this issue.

I've done a bit of reading online about the update and I have updated my AndroidManifest.xml to this:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

So as you can see I'm asking for `read_media_images` to be able to pick images and `manage_external_storage` to have access to the file system and pick PDF files.
That being said, the documentation of the plugin `permission_handler` states that the manage external storage is considered "dangerous" by Google and requires to fill privacy declaration forms if the app is to be published.

My question is as follows: in the light of the new update to permissions, what is the best way to ask my user for permission to access their files and let them upload PDF to the app while not using a method considered dangerous ?

Note that I'm currently using `FilePicker` to pick my files and I'd like not to have to re-write all that code with a different package.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Identify a Flutter package that wraps the Storage Access Framework on Android, and use it. This will use a system picker to allow the user to choose a PDF from an available storage location (on-device or in a cloud provider).

Comment: `you can see I'm asking for read_media_images to be able to pick images ` You do not need any permission to be able to pick images with the usual actions.

Comment: @CommonsWare Any recommendation ?

Comment: @blackapps noted ! Though my problem here is more so with pdf, image work as is even with superfluous permissions.

Comment: I am not a Flutter developer, sorry.

Comment: You do not need any permission to be able to pick pdf files with the usual actions.

Comment: @blackapps I'm sorry what ? I tried to do `Filepicker.platform.pickFile` without asking for the right permission and it's not working, what do you mean by usual action ?

Comment: ACTION_GET_CONTENT, ACTION_,OPEN_DOCUMENT, ACTION_PICK.

Comment: @Tom did u find any solution???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was Frustrating to solve myself.
Apparently Android 13 on Flutter does not need permission or a package to work.
Remove permission handler for storage and it will work just  fine because in API 33 no such permission exist so it will always return empty.
Code Below

```
Future<bool> checkStoragePermission(BuildContext context) async {
 if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    final DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    final AndroidDeviceInfo info = await deviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo;
    if ((info.version.sdkInt ?? 0) >= 33) 
       return true;
  }
  if (!await requestPermission(<Permission>[Permission.storage])) {
    
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

When the above is true, call the next section

```
Future<File?> pickPDFFile() async {
    final result = await _filePicker.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['pdf'],
      allowMultiple: false,
      withData: true,
    );
    if (result != null && result.files.first.extension == 'pdf') {
      return File(result.files.first.path!);
    } else {
      _filePicker.clearTemporaryFiles();
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: That's close to what I ended up doing, though I'm not sure how to handle the case where the user refuses access to his files or camer. For the default case of a user that doesn't go out of their way to restrict access, this is a good solution.